# Sort based on how many items are in an array using mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Post` model that has a `likes` array that contains the `ObjectId` of the user that liked the Post, I would like to sort Posts based on how many likes they have received.

I'm sure I would use `$size`, `$sort` and `aggregate`, but everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. Can you use `$size` within `$sort`? What would be the correct way of doing this? and is there a specific way of doing it with mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      size: { $size: "$likes" }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      size: -1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JepqHmSF8Mh)